# 403 Forbidden : Axios response ; React js

Tags: reactjs, axios

- Trying to query antifactory using React/Axios using two different way which axios provides

1.) Working perfectly fine: Getting response 200 and apikey in response:

```js
export async function validateArtfKey(base64: string) {
  var axios = require('axios');

  var config = {
    method: 'get',
    url: 'https://example.com/artifactory/api/security/apiKey',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + base64
    }
  };

  axios(config)
    .then(function (response: { data: any; }) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
    })
    .catch(function (error: any) {
      console.log(error);
    })
}

</script>
```

2.) This method responds with: 403 forbidden

```js
export async function validateArtfKey(base64: string) {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + base64
    }
  };
  try {
    const response = await axios.get("https://example.com/artifactory/api/security/apikey", config);
    if (response.status === 200) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
    } else {
      console.log("Failed to fetch Arftifactory apikey", response.data);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Can any one notice the difference why method 2 is responding **403**. I have used method 2 for most of api queries throughout my application and is working good.

Comment: Are the URLs case-sensitive?

Comment: @DaveNewton, Not case sensitive

Comment: can you create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I've tried your code snippet with another API URL (since I do not have the API key), everything working properly with two versions of your function.